# Can MBTiles file exported with QGIS "Generate XYZ Tiles" tool be uploaded as a tileset to Mapbox?

Tags: qgis, tiles, mapbox, tilemill, mbtiles

I am wondering if the files generated with this tool are analogous with the exports from the discontinued Mapbox styling UI TileMill. My test of exporting the same display with both tools yields two .mbtiles files with wildly different file sizes. Has anyone tried to upload a .mbtiles file exported with this QGIS tool into Mapbox?

Comment: It should work, have you tried was there a specific error?